# ¿Cómo comparar elementos de una matriz?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este ejercicio: "Leer una matriz 4x6 entera y determinar si alguno de sus números está repetido al menos 3 veces."

Lo que tengo hasta el momento es esto:

```
"""
Este programa lee una matriz 4x6 entera y determina si alguno de sus números
está repetido al menos 3 veces.
"""

# Declaración de constantes.
Nfil = 4  # Número de filas de la matriz.
Ncol = 6  # Número de columnas de la matriz.


def crear_matriz(f, c):

""" Crea una matriz con f filas y c columnas con elementos ingresados por el
    usuario.

    crear_matriz(f, c)

    Parámetros de entrada:
        f = Número de filas que tiene la matriz.
        c = Número de columnas que tiene la matriz.

    Retorna una lista de listas (Matriz).
"""

m = [[None for i in range(c)] for j in range(f)]
# El siguiente ciclo anidado primero toma una fila y luego va columna a
# columna y va agregando en cada posición el número que el usuario ingresa.
for fila in range(f):
    for columna in range(c):
        while True:
            try:
                num = int(input("\n[{0}][{1}] Ingrese un entero:   "
                                .format(fila+1, columna+1)))
                if type(num) == int:
                    break  # Saldra del ciclo para pedir un nuevo número.
            except ValueError:
                print("\nERROR\nPor favor solo ingrese números enteros")
        m[fila][columna] = num  # Agrega el entero ingresado a la matriz.
return m


############################## Programa principal ##############################

# Se guardan las matrices creadas con los enteros que ingresó el usuario.
matriz = crear_matriz(Nfil, Ncol)

# El siguiente ciclo anidado primero toma una fila y luego va columna a
# columna leyendo en cada posición el número que el usuario ingresó. (Matriz_1)

for fila in range(Nfil):
    for columna in range(Ncol):
        Comparador = int(matriz[fila][columna])
```

No sé cómo seguir para comparar en cada cada elemento de la matriz, les agradecería su ayuda es urgente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dispone de una clase [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) que almacena los elementos como claves del diccionario y sus ocurrencias como valores del diccionario. Para poder utilizarlo debes importarlo del módulo `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter
```

Para poder utilizar la matriz directamente en el objeto `Counter` hay que aplanarla primero (o almacenar directamente los números en una lista secuencialmente). Para transformar la matriz en una lista puedes utilizar una [lista por comprensión](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/datastructures.html#comprension-de-listas):

```
list = [i for x in matriz for i in x]
```

Ahora sólo es necesario crear un contador:

```
count = Counter(list)
```

E iterar los elementos del diccionario resultante para mostrar los que tengan más de 3 ocurrencias:

```
for i in count.keys():
    if count[i] >= 3:
        print("El elemento %d está repetido %d veces" % (i, count[i]))
```

Si quieres prescindir de la clase `Counter`, simplemente debes iterar la matriz e ir almacenando en un diccionario el número de veces que aparece cada elemento:

```
count = dict()
for i in range(Nfil):
    for j in range(Ncol):
        if count.get(matriz[i][j]) == None:
            count[matriz[i][j]] = 0
        count[matriz[i][j]] += 1
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió mucho, solo me queda una duda que se hace  en está parte del código (utilicé la segunda opción):
if count.get(matriz[i][j]) == None:                                                                                                                                                    Qué hace el metodo .get() ?

Comment: @RichardA.RamosTrujillo el método `get` de los diccionarios  retorna el valor asociado a la clave pasada como primer argumento, pero a diferencia de `dict[key]`,  no lanza un _KeyError_ si la clave no se encuentra en el diccionario, sino que retorna el valor del argumento `default`, que por defecto es `None`. Por tanto, lo que hace `if count.get(matriz[i][j]) == None:` es comprobar si la clave `matriz[i][j]` existe o no en el diccionario, si no existe la crea en la linea siguiente. Esta es la documentación oficial: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.get

Comment: Otra opción mas directa de hacer la misma comprobación es con `if not matriz[i][j]) in count:`. Cabe decir que `collections.Counter` es considerablemente más eficiente al hacer uso de código C en su totalidad, más aún si eliminamos la lista intermedia en memoria para aplanar la matriz usando simplemente un generador por compresión `count = Counter(i for x in matriz for i in x)`